# Shell - aapt output into variable

Tags: android, macos, shell, apk

I use following command to get my APK versionName

```
PATH/aapt dump badging APK-Path | grep versionName
```

And it works fine if I run it on it's own but I need it in a variable so I try sth like this:

```
$s='PATH/aapt dump badging APK-Path | grep versionName'
```

but it returns

> PATH/aapt dump badging APK-Path | grep versionName no such file or
>   directory

error. I also tried using `$()` instead of `''`. Any ideas how to make it work?

EDIT.: I use terminal in MacOS. if I enter PATH I can just run `aapt dump badging APK-Path | grep versionName` but if I don't do that I need to pass it as shown above

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean bash (or the like) when you say shell, you probably want to do something like this:
`s="PATH/aapt dump badging APK-Path | grep versionName"` or `s="$(PATH/aapt dump badging APK-Path | grep versionName)"`

You can then retrieve the value of s with `echo $s`

Comment: Using you solution - removing $ from my example - puts command as string into variable. I need to put output of command into variable

Comment: Then you must not be using bash, as my answer assumes. As an example, in bash   x=$(ls)   will store the results of a directory listing into x.   echo $x   will then display the results. Also, your use of PATH seems a bit odd. I assumed that was literally part of the command's path and that you weren't trying to access the value of the common shell variable named PATH.

Comment: I use MacOS terminal. I need to enter PATH or pass it in call. If I cd into PATH I can just run `aapt dump badging APK-Path | grep versionName` with same result as `PATH/aapt dump badging APK-Path | grep versionName`
My apologies for lack of clarity in question - I added these info in question